# Open a specific bootstrap tab on page load using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I try to open a `Bootstrap v.3` tab on page load using `jQuery`. I tried the

```
$('#activeTab3').addClass("active");
```

and

```
$('#activeTab3').tab('show')
```

which colors the button in the navigation list, but the content which is shown is belongs to the 1st tab.

I also tried:

```
$("#mytabs").tabs({
  active: 1
});
```

but I get an error that tabs isn't a function..

```js
$('#activeTab3').addClass("active");

//$('#activeTab3').tab('show')


/*
$("#mytabs").tabs({
  active: 1
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mtop-2">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-10">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" id="mytabs">
        <li role="presentation" id="activeTab1"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" id="activeTab2"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" id="activeTab3"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMachine1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseMachine1">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> panel 1-1
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseMachine1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseMachine1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row mtop-2">
                    .... panel 1-1
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMachine2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMachine2">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit mright-1"></i> panel 1-2
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseMachine2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseMachine2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  .... panel 1-3
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseRobot1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseRobot1">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> panel 2-1
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseRobot1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseRobot1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  panel 2-1
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseRobot2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseRobot2">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit mright-1"></i> panel 2-2
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseRobot2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseRobot2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  panel 2-2

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMould1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseMould1">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> panel 3-1
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseMould1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseMould1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  panel 3-1
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMould2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMould2">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit mright-1"></i> panel 3-2
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseMould2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseMould2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  panel 3-2
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#mytabs a[href="#tab3"]').tab('show') 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mtop-2">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-10">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist" id="mytabs">
        <li role="presentation" ><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">tab3</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMachine1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseMachine1">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> panel 1-1
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseMachine1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseMachine1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="row mtop-2">
                    .... panel 1-1
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMachine2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMachine2">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit mright-1"></i> panel 1-2
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseMachine2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseMachine2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  .... panel 1-3
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseRobot1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseRobot1">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> panel 2-1
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseRobot1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseRobot1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  panel 2-1
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseRobot2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseRobot2">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit mright-1"></i> panel 2-2
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseRobot2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseRobot2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  panel 2-2

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMould1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseMould1">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> panel 3-1
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseMould1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseMould1">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  panel 3-1
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseMould2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMould2">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit mright-1"></i> panel 3-2
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseMould2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="collapseMould2">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  panel 3-2
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use `$('#mytabs a[href="#tab3"]').tab('show')` to select tab using the tab css id and href css id.